# find common unique elements of lists and returning None if empty list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why the last part of my code doesn't work?

```
def common_elements(list1, list2):


    #a list with common element
    common_elements=[]
    common_unique_elements=[]

    for i in list1:
        if i in list2:
            common_elements.append(i)
    #removing repeated elements
            for i in common_elements:
                if i not in common_unique_elements:
                    common_unique_elements.append(i)
    #returning None for empty list                
                    if len(common_elements)==0:
                        return None
    return sorted(common_unique_elements)
```

Comment: Have you looked at python’s sets?

Comment: I shouldn't use sets for this question.

Comment: First, peoples asking questions here also contribute to community growth by keeping their text format standard, and their questions informative. In case of troubleshooting, always include your errors, as it is easier to trace back the error in your code. 
Here I think the problem is that you use `common_unique_elements` name twice (your function name, and a list inside the function) so I ran into this error `'function' object has no attribute 'append'`. changing your function name or your list name might solve the problem. check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no need of a second list just to hold unique common elements. You can do the check before you add to first list, thus avoiding the need of second list:

```
def common_elements(list1, list2):
    common = []
    for i in list1:
        if i in list2 and i not in common:
            common.append(i)                
    return None if not common else sorted(common)

list1 = ['a','b','b,','c']
list2 = ['f','b','e','a','a']

print(common_elements(list1, list2))
# ['a', 'b']
```

Avoid using function name for variables; can run into problems later.